# Copy files with new sequential name (Linux)

Tags: linux, cp, seq

I have this file named **checkinout100.php** and need to copy it to another 100 files following the numbered sequence like **checkinout101.php**, **checkinout102.php** and so on until 200.
I've been looking to do it with **seq** but can't figure it out on my own.
Thanks.

NOTE: Has nothing to do with webpages. It's an Asterisk PBX (Yeastar), I need one of those files per extension (link with hotel software).

Comment: I can only imagine the atrocity you are about to create with these 100 php files. I think you're missing the point.

Comment: why on earth would you want to do this? - the more proper solution here would be to use a get or post method to set the number; checkinout.php?number=101

Comment: @JonathonReinhart don't ask, lol. It's an Asterisk device connected with hotel software, it really need's those files, one for each extension.

Comment: Either you're missing something or that is the most asinine software ever created.

Comment: ok.. if not a wep page, you couild probably have used commandline arguments, but... hey... http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: @Henrik, I understand. However, this is a PBX system that links with hotel software. It's a requirement of that software, so my hands are tied and just had to create the files :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `seq` in the following way:

```
for n in $(seq 101 200) ; do
    cp checkinout100.php checkinout$n.php
done
```